# Make event occur on button click every twenty seconds in Asp.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

Once I click on a button, I am trying to get a certain action happen every day, but for testing purposed, I'm trying to get it to happen every 20 seconds, just to see that it works. Currently, nothing happens and I have no idea where I'm going wrong.

```
  public void AddIncoming_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (frequencyIncoming.SelectedValue == "Weekly")
        {
            DateTime weekly = DateTime.Now;
            for (DateTime current = weekly; current == current.AddSeconds(20);)
            {
                //totalCalculation = (totalCalculation + Convert.ToDouble(costIncoming));
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + DateTime.Now + "');", true);
            }

        }

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Incomings (AspNetUsersId,IncType,IncDate,IncCost,IncFrequency) values (@AspNetUsersId, @IncType, @IncDate, @IncCost, @IncFrequency)");

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AspNetUsersId", userId);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IncType", typeIncoming.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IncDate", lblCalendar.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IncCost", costIncoming.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IncFrequency", frequencyIncoming.Text);

        loadDatabase(cmd);

        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);

    }
```

Any information is greatly appreciated!
Cheers

Comment: So whenever the button is clicked, you want whatever thread is handling the event to idle in a while loop for 20 seconds, then at the end of 20 seconds to do some stuff and return?

Comment: Well the idea would be for me to be able to continue browsing the website whilst this is running in the background. But if I even got it working for demonstration purposes that would be sufficient. I'm not too sure how to go about it

Comment: A webpage cannot continue running on the server while you "continue browsing the website". You need to look into using a background thread (not reliable, especially for something you want to happen every day) or a job scheduler (highly recommended) to handle this.

Comment: Ok I will look into this, thank you mark

Answer (score 0):

edit: Actually, just do this (probably put some logic in to set "keepLooping = false" if you can detect that the program is shutting down):

```
public void AddIncoming_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (frequencyIncoming.SelectedValue == "Weekly")
    {
        DateTime weekly = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan timeToWait = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 5); // days, hours, minutes, seconds
        bool keepLooping = true;
        while (keepLooping)
        {
            if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(weekly) < timeToWait)
            {
                //sleep 1 second while waiting so cpu doesn't spin at maximum
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            else
            {
                // this code will run every ~timeToWait
                Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.Subtract(weekly)} seconds have elapsed.");
                weekly = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }
    }

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Incomings (AspNetUsersId,IncType,IncDate,IncCost,IncFrequency) values (@AspNetUsersId, @IncType, @IncDate, @IncCost, @IncFrequency)");

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AspNetUsersId", userId);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IncType", typeIncoming.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IncDate", lblCalendar.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IncCost", costIncoming.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IncFrequency", frequencyIncoming.Text);

    loadDatabase(cmd);

    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help I will give this a go now. The first bit of code worked but it only did it once instead of every 20 seconds. I appreciate it!

Comment: @Stuart Oh ok I edited it back and now stuff will run every ~20 seconds.

Comment: Yea I fired it in a for loop and it worked grand but I'll give this a go now. Thank you!

Comment: This will not survive app pool recycling

Comment: what would you recommend to survive the execution timeout mark?